# Erro no 'grunt build'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Não estou entendendo muito bem o motivo desse erro e como solucioná-lo

> ```
> npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-116-generic
> npm ERR! argv "/home/fmessias/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/bin/node" "/home/fmessias/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/bin/npm" "run" "build"
> npm ERR! node v7.9.0
> npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
> npm ERR! file sh
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall spawn
> npm ERR! node-red@0.16.2 build: `grunt build`
> npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the node-red@0.16.2 build script 'grunt build'.
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-red package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     grunt build
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
> npm ERR!     npm bugs node-red
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-red
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /home/fmessias/.npm/_logs/2017-04-20T17_54_48_272Z-debug.log
> ```

Esse erro ocorre ao tentar dar *build* no projeto.

Comment: A task de build foi desenvolvida por você mesmo?

Comment: Não. Estou estudando o node-RED, pra isso estou fazendo algumas alterações na interface e etc. Quando fui dar build no projeto me deparei com esse erro

Comment: Coloca na sua pergunta o conteúdo daquele último arquivo citado.